# How do I create a wagon wheel kind of graph for the runs scored by players in a React native app

Tags: react-native

[Wagon Wheel Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IB3b.png)
My Graph looks like above. What I was thinking was to put the ground image in background and then do the graph in top if it. But Somehow I am not getting idea on how do i draw the run scored lines for the graph

I want the graph to be exactly as same as in image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't coded anything yet for it, I am looking for the path to go ahead with